# Makefile: why is a conditional block ignored immediately after .suffixes?

Tags: makefile

Can anybody explain why the conditional `ifneq` block is ignored if it comes immediately after the `.SUFFIXES:` target, but not if there is something in between?

```
COMPILE_FLAGS = -Wextra -Wall -g -fopenmp
LINK_FLAGS = -lm -fopenmp
PKG_CONFIG_LIBS = glib-2.0

# Disable all default implicit rules
.SUFFIXES:

# If the following line is uncommented, the pkg-config
# block works perfectly, not if it is not.
#BOGUS = 

ifneq ($(PKG_CONFIG_LIBS),)
    COMPILE_FLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(PKG_CONFIG_LIBS))
    LINK_FLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --libs $(PKG_CONFIG_LIBS))
endif

%.o: %.c
    gcc $(COMPILE_FLAGS) -c $<

caca: caca.o
    gcc $(COMPILE_FLAGS) $(LINK_FLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm caca *.o
```

It is not that the first thing after `.SUFFIXES:` is ignored: if the `BOGUS` line is uncommented, that variable does take the value you want to set it to, and if not only  the `BOGUS` line but also the conditional block is commented, the pattern rule still works. Any ideas? Thanks!

UPDATE: I am running GNU Make 4.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64. The exact output of the proposed Makefile for me is, no matter if I insert an `$(info hello)` inside the `ifneq` block):

```
$ make
gcc -Wextra -Wall -g -fopenmp -c caca.c
gcc -Wextra -Wall -g -fopenmp -lm -fopenmp -o caca caca.o
```

However, if I uncomment the `BOGUS` line, the result is, as expected:

```
$ make
gcc -Wextra -Wall -g -fopenmp -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -c caca.c
gcc -Wextra -Wall -g -fopenmp -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lm -fopenmp -lglib-2.0 -o caca caca.o
```

Comment: You'll have to provide more information.  I cannot reproduce your results, using any version of GNU make from 3.79 to the current latest release.  What version of GNU make are you using?  What operating system?  Please show the output you get.  If you add something like `$(info hello)` inside the `ifneq` block does it get printed?  Are you sure you tried this _exact_ example and verified you see the behavior with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have spurious tab characters as shown:-

```
ifneq ($(PKG_CONFIG_LIBS),)
<tab>COMPILE_FLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(PKG_CONFIG_LIBS))
<tab>LINK_FLAGS += $(shell pkg-config --libs $(PKG_CONFIG_LIBS))
endif
```

which cause the tabbed lines to be construed as a recipe of the pseudo-target `.SUFFIXES`
when they are the first non-empty, non-comment lines that follow that target,
and the controlling `ifneq` is true. In this case, they are *not* executed when you run `make`,
even though `ifneq` is evaluated, and true. They would be passed to the shell for execution, 
after `$(...)` expansion, if the pseudo-target `.SUFFIXES:` was selected.

The pseudo-target is ignored by `make` as a candidate default target, so
when you simply run `make`, you observe that the default target is `caca`
and that the tabbed lines have been "ignored". But if you run:

```
make .SUFFIXES
```

(keeping `BOGUS` commented out), you will see:

```
COMPILE_FLAGS += 
make: COMPILE_FLAGS: Command not found
Makefile:13: recipe for target '.SUFFIXES' failed
make: *** [.SUFFIXES] Error 127
```

making it clear that the tabbed lines are indeed a recipe (though one
of which the shell can't make sense).

To fix, either delete those tabs or replace them with spaces. The
prudent habit is never to tab-indent lines in a makefile unless you intend the
tabbed lines to be a recipe.